# Rails Scaffold Generator ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I used the scaffold generator to generate a title (string) and body (content) so I can create 'posts'.

When I generatored this model, is there a way I can have `<%= posts.id %>` so:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div id="<%= posts.id %>">
    <%= post.title %>       
  </div>
<% end %>
```

### Update

Apologies for the confusion. What I meant to say is when you generate a model, does it come with an ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing 'posts' which doesn't exist.

@posts is a collection of posts, so there's no id on that either.

Each post will have an id though, so you can do post.id inside that block just as you have post.title (singular)

Comment: Cool, please check the response that answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Modify the views the way you want, you don't need to keep them like they are after scaffolding. Scaffolding (and all other generators) are just there to make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `<%= div_for post %>` which will give you the post id, or change your `posts.id` to `post.id`